# Prove that $\mathcal{B}=(f_1,...,f_k,g_1,...,g_{n-k})$ is a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space with $\dim(V)=n$. If
>   $\mathcal{A}=(f_1,...,f_k)$ is a basis of $W$, show there exists
>   $g_1,...,g_{n-k}\in V-W$ such that
>   $\mathcal{B}=(f_1,...,f_k,g_1,...,g_{n-k})$ is a basis of $V$.
>
> Additionally, show that every subspace $W\subseteq V$ has a linear
>   transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that $\ker(T)=W$.

For the first question, can we just say that $g_1,...g_{n-k}$ can be linearly independent vectors in $V\cup W$, so that the set $\mathcal{B}=(f_1,...,f_k,g_1,...,g_n-k)$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors, so that they also span the $n$-dimensional space $V$?

I'm not really sure about the second question. Help would be appreciated there.

Comment: The idea is to use the first part to construct the linear transformation $T$ sought in the second part. An arbitrary vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $f_{i}$ and $g_{j}$ in a unique way. The linear transformation that throws away the terms in the $f_{i}$ has kernel equal to the span of the $f_{i}$, which is $W$.

Comment: What results can you use? It's a basic result that any linearly independent set can always be completed to form a basis of the total space: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337353/linearly-independent-set-can-be-completed-to-a-basis