# Determining a basis of a vector space (Linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the following statement or provide a counter example if it is false.

A basis {$b_{1}$,.....,$b_{k}$} of any $k$ dimensional subspace $S$ of an n dimensional vector space $V$ can be extended to a basis of $V$ by including $n-k$ more vectors with the basis.

The statement is true because adding a vector to a basis will still make it linearly independent. Hence we can add as many vectors as we want until we reach the maximum of $n$ vectors. Is my answer correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: The statement is a bit imprecise and may or may not be true depending on how you read it. You cannot just add any vector to the given set, cause that may be in the span of the given set. Any vector you may want to add needs to have the property that the resulting set is still linear independent. How do you find such vectors?

Comment: The vectors that we add cannot be a linear combination of the vectors that are already in the span.?

Comment: If you add a vector in the span of the given set it can be linearly combined by the set (by definition of span).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that any linearly independent subset of $V$ can be extended to a basis of $V$.ofcourse,$\{b_1,b_2,...b_k\}$ is linearly independent.Hence done.

**Added:** If you don't know the proof of this result you can found it here:[Linearly independent set can be completed to a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337353/linearly-independent-set-can-be-completed-to-a-basis)

Comment: You're restating exactly what's to be proved.

Comment: @egreg I've added a link for proof of this result.Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove that if $\{b_1,b_2,b_k\}$ is linearly independent, then either it is a basis of $V$ or there exists a vector $b_{k+1}$ such that $\{b_1,b_2,b_k,b_{k+1}\}$ is linearly independent.

Indeed, if the set is not a basis of $V$, then it is not a spanning set; let $b_{k+1}\in V$ but not in the span of $\{b_1,b_2,b_k\}$. It's easy to see that $\{b_1,b_2,b_k,b_{k+1}\}$ is linearly independent (show it).

Now, starting from the given basis of $S$, apply repeatedly the lemma just proved until the set you get spans $V$. This must happen after $n-k$ repetitions, because a linearly independent set with $n=\dim V$ elements is a basis.